# Make a wireframe Polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make some graphs to help some calculus students that I am tutoring better visualize the solids that they are finding the volume of. For example, one problem is to find the volume of a triangular pyramid.

Below is some working code which generates the sides of the pyramid, but you can't tell where one side ends and the other begins. How can I turn this into a wireframe to make the solid more recognizable? Or, alternatively, how could I color the surfaces in different colors to make the figure more visible?

Specifically, I do not understand how I could make a triangular mesh grid. Alternatively, I guess making lines that connect to each point would be sufficient.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

fig = plot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

A=[0,0,0]
B=[1,1,0]
C=[0,1,1]
D=[0,1,0]

verts=[[A,B,C],
       [A,B,D],
       [A,D,C],
       [B,C,D]]

ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
ax.view_init(azim=-45)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z') 
plot.show()
```

The resulting figure:

[image: triangular pyramid visualization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the edges of your shape, you can specify the [line width](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_linewidth) when creating the `Poly3DCollection`

```
Poly3DCollection(verts, lw=2)
```

[image]

Also, specifying some [face transparency](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_alpha) may help with visualization

```
Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolor=(0,0,1,0.2), linewidth=2, edgecolor=(0,0,0))
```

[image]

You can also use the [`facecolors`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_facecolor) property to specify a different color for each face

```
Poly3DCollection(verts, lw=2, facecolors=['r', 'g', 'b', 'k'])
```

[image]

Comment: The second picture you have is exactly what I want. When I add the `lw=2` and `alpha=.5` to my code, the graph is unaffected. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: @K.Shores And you're just adding it to the creation of the `Poly3DCollection`?

Comment: Yes. I changed the line from this `ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))` to `ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, lw=2, alpha=.5))`.

Comment: @K.Shores Are you just visualizing it or saving it to an external file?

Comment: I am saving it to an external file with `plot.savefig("example.png")`. Note: the line `plot.show()` does not appear in the code that I am running to generate the file `example.png`.

Comment: @K.Shores Hmmm I'm not sure. Doing the exact same thing with your code  on my machine yields the images you see above. And you're sure that you're running the updated and saved script? What operating system?

Comment: Yes, I am sure I am running the updated version. I am using Python 3.6 on macOS 10.12.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134280/discussion-between-suever-and-k-shores).